# Let $f,f' \in L^1$, show $\int_\mathbb{R} f'=0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f,f' \in L^1$, $f$ is differentiable everywhere,  show $\int_\mathbb{R} f'=0$

I have no clue how to do this problem. I had some ideas but they all require extra assumptions like:

$f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ or $f'$ is bounded on each compact set. Any hints would be appreciated.

I was trying to mess around with $\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}$ and try to move the limit around but could not justify doing that. If I could the result would easily follow from translation invariance. I was thinking MVT could help us find a dominating function ($f'$) but I do not think that is the case.

Comment: does $R = \mathbb{R}$ in your post?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Yes

Comment: I tried a solution but I made a mistake sorry

Comment: @GiuseppeTenaglia No problem! I made exactly the same mistake when first attempting this problem :P

Comment: The deleted answer was on the right track. You need to prove that the assumptions you have imply that $$\lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x)=0.$$

Comment: I was wandering if you could just write the $f'= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and then using the fact that $f' \in L^1$ to bring the limit outside the integral with lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GiuseppeTenaglia I am not sure what dominates the ratio. My worry was that MVT does not guarantee an actual function that bounds the ratio.

Comment: Saying $f,f' \in L^1$ implies they exist a.e., does not imply $f'$ exists everywhere, and does not imply $\int_a^b f'(x)\;dx = f(b)=f(a)$.

Comment: @GEdgar That is my fault, $f$ is differentiable. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I am assuming that $f'$ exists **everywhere**.

We have $f(b)-f(a) = \int_a^b f'(t)dt$. Since $f'$ is integrable we see that
$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exist, call them $f(-\infty)$ and $f(\infty)$ respectively.

Suppose $f(-\infty) >0$, then for some $M$ if $x<M$, we have
$f(x)>{1 \over 2} f(-\infty)$ and hence
if $a,b <M$ we have $\int_a^b f(s)ds > {1 \over 2}f(\infty)(b-a)$ in which
case $f$ is not integrable. Similarly if $f(-\infty) <0$.

Repeat the process to get  $f(\infty) = 0$.

Hence $f(\infty)-f(\infty) = 0 -0 =  \int f'$.

**Aside**:

If we drop the requirement that $f'$ exists everywhere then the result is not true. For example, $f(x)=x \cdot 1_{[0,1]}$ is differentiable everywhere except $0,1$ and both $f,f'$ are integrable, but
$\int f' = {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: Could you explain how do we have The first equation? Could you elaborate why the limits exist? To be honest these are the parts I had trouble proving.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus applies for integrable functions.

Comment: Could you give me a reference to that? I thought it works only when $f'$ is actually bounded. I could have sworn I saw counterexamples of this claim here on stack exchange.

Comment: Well, I was a little sloppy, you need $f'$ to exist everywhere and $f$ to be integrable. It is a fairly standard result, for example Rudin's "Real & Complex Analysis", Theorem 7.21.

Comment: Hmm, So this implies that every differentiable function on a compact set is absolutely continuous?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. If $f$ is differentiable at every point in $[a,b]$ and $f'$ is  integrable then $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: ah, given $f' \in L^1$ I see. Thank you, will ahve to study the proof of 7.21

Comment: Sorry, I'm dropping $f'$s left right & centre.

Comment: Basically, if $f'$ exists everywhere the fundamental theorem of calculus always holds if we use Denjoy Integrals; if $f'$ satisfies extra conditions (bounded or integrable) than we can use Lebesgue integration as noted by @copper; if $f'$ exists only ae things can break down badly

Comment: Could someone explain why the limit must exist since $f'$ is integrable? By integrating from $[0,n]$ and noting that the limit is $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)-f(0)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f'$?

Comment: Because the integral exists if you let  either $a,b$ go to $-\infty, \infty$ respectively. Use the dominate convergence theorem on $f' \cdot 1_{[a,b]}$.